# How to return error as value from failable function?

Tags: error-handling, zig

*The current release of Zig is 0.10.1 at the time of asking this question.  The language is not yet stable and is subject to change.*

How can I return an error as value from a failable function?  I have tried the following, but it returns it as an error instead of returning it as a value:

```
fn foo_1() !anyerror {
    // Returns outer error.
    return error.Oops;
}

fn foo_2() !anyerror {
    // Returns outer error.
    var error_ = error.Oops;
    return error_;
}
```

I would like to return it as value such that the following code to print out the error instead of propagating it when `try` is evaluated:

```
fn bar() !void {
    var error_ = try foo();
    std.debug.print("got error: {any}\n", .{ error_ });
}
```

I am asking this because I am trying to learn the language.  I don't have a concrete use-case for this.  However, I am curious if this is possible to do.

---

A similar related situation is to return an optional value which itself is optional (for example when forwarding the result of a function which returns an optional), but I was already able to find a solution for that:

```
fn baz_1() ??i32 {
   // The outer optional is null.
   return null;
}

fn baz_2() ??i32 {
   // The inner optional is null.
   var value: ?i32 = null;
   return value;
}
```

Is something like that possible for errors as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not allowed in Zig. If you try you'll get an error like "error union with payload of error set type 'error{Def}' not allowed".

However, you can wrap the error in a struct:

```
const std = @import("std");

const ErrorError = error{
    Abc,
};

const ErrorValue = error{
    Def,
};

const WrappedError = struct {
    err: ErrorValue,
};

fn foo() ErrorError!WrappedError {
    return .{
        .err = ErrorValue.Def,
    };
}

test "returns error value" {
    var bar = try foo();
    std.debug.assert(bar.err == ErrorValue.Def);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to produce that error message. However, you seem to be correct, [this issue](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/7913) discusses this exact problem. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because I'm not using 0.10.1, but 0.11.0-dev.1491+2b27bc2c6.

Answer (score 0):

error values can be declared with `error{...}` syntax. see https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Errors

```rs
pub const Error = error{Bar};

fn foo() error{Bar} {
    return error.Bar;
}

fn foo() Error {
    return error.Bar;
}
```

Comment: What I want is a function that returns an error but that function can also fail in some other way. When it fails that should be different from when it returns an error as value. Your functions return an error but they can't fail.

Comment: `error{Foo}!error{Bar}`

Comment: [That does not compile.](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fzcWsvWes) It produces the error `error union with payload of error set type 'error{Bar}' not allowed`.

Comment: so return a tuple/struct with error field